# Stop R from changing "" to \" in csv files.

Tags: r

I have an input csv file, `Input.csv`, that looks like this:

```
"VariableOne";"VariableTwo"
"Hello, how are you?";"I'm fine, thank you!"
"He said ""how are you?"" to her";"She responded ""I'm fine, thank you!"" and then left."
"Good bye!";"Good bye!"
```

Note the double quotes, `""`, for quotes within the variable text.

Now, I have an R program that looks like this:

```
Data <- read.csv2("./Input.csv",header=TRUE, sep=";", quote="\"")
write.table(Data,file="Output.csv",sep=";",row.names=FALSE, quote=TRUE)
```

This program generates the following output csv file, `Output.csv`:

```
"VariableOne";"VariableTwo"
"Hello, how are you?";"I'm fine, thank you!"
"He said \"how are you?\" to her";"She responded \"I'm fine, thank you!\" and then left."
"Good bye!";"Good bye!"
```

Note that the double quotes, `""`, have been replaced by `\"`. This causes a lot of problem for me down the pipeline, and I would like the double quotes, `""`, to be left untouched for the output.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `qmethod` parameter in `write.table`, and set it to "double" in order to produce the quoting behavior as `""` rather than `\"` for specifying embedded quotes.

Your command would be:

```
write.table(Data,file="Output.csv",sep=";",row.names=FALSE, quote=TRUE, qmethod="double")
```